# running same script for 2 different files (input & output) ??? /ROOT/C++

Tags: c++, root-framework

I have a script that reads a tree and creates some plots.

I have two files I need to run, so I need to run the same script once for `file1` and once for `file2`, storing results in a different output file each time.

How can I tell my program what file to run each time and where to save the results?

`file1` is: `flatTree_jetHT`
`outputfile1` is: `flatTree_JetHT_output.root`

`file2` is: `flatTree_jetHT2`
`outputfile2` is: `flatTree_JetHT2_output.root`

I need to write this down using just one void and telling which file to run from terminal (`.x flatTree_jetHt_read.C`)

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
void flatTree_jetHT_read()
{

  gROOT->Reset();
  gROOT->SetStyle("Plain"); 
  gStyle->SetOptStat(1);
  gStyle->SetOptFit(0);
  gStyle->SetPadColor(0);
  gStyle->SetPalette(1);

  TFile *f = TFile::Open("flatTree_JetHT.root", "READ");
  TTree *tree = (TTree*)f->Get("boosted/events");
  TFile *outf = TFile::Open("flatTree_JetHT_output.root", "RECREATE");
//more code....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just passing the input/output as arguments of the function? (see the [Getting Started](https://root.cern.ch/root/htmldoc/guides/users-guide/ROOTUsersGuide.html) section of the user guide).

```
void two_args(const char* input_file, const char* output_file)
{
    printf("Input: '%s'\n", input_file);
    printf("Output: '%s'\n", output_file);
}
```

then run as

```
$ root -l -x -q '/tmp/two_args.C+("in.root", "out.root")'
```